# hide a plaintext file(python tkinter)

Tags: python

**situation**

As soon as the application starts, I decrypt all the stored data(which is encrypted using ARC4) and store it in a file. Now the application runs full screen, But if the user minimises this window and looks in his files manager(nemo, explorer etc) then He/she will see a file that is in plain-text. This will cause all the data to be compromised and obviously I don't want that to happen. Once the application is closed, Then I encrypt the data and delete the plaintext file using`os.remove` and store only the encrypted data. It is the time when the application is running that I am worried about. The data stored is account information(usernames, passwords etc).

**question**

So is there a way to somehow hide this plain-text file so that the user is unable to see it in his file manager but I can access it from the program?

**hurdle :(**

I can't change the whole design of the program because I am running against a deadline and it is a big application and will simply take too much time. **please** help me with this issue.

**specs**

I am using Python 2.7 on a Linux Mint machine.

Comment: Writing it unencrypted to the hard drive already compromises the data to some extent. There are possibilities like processing the data in another user account (if current user isn't an administrator of the machine)

Comment: You shouldn't be storing passwords (even encrypted) in the first place! And Python (when run locally) is not a good solution for security-relevant applications because the user always has access (or can trivially gain it) to the source code, so anything you do can be reproduced by an attacker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a really, *really*, bad idea to store sensitive data in a plain-text file. You should really be decrypting the data only when you need it, and using it immediately in the program without having to write it out to a file.

However, assuming that you already know this and you just want a quick-fix to hide a file, then you could:

- Make the file name start with a `.` - for example `.data`. This will make the file hidden on unix-based systems.
- Place the file in an obscure location that the user is not likely to search, such as `/tmp`
- Don't give the file an obvious name, like `passwords.txt`, but instead use a generated name from a hash function or timestamp - such as `time.time()`. This will have the added benefit of making your filename different each time the program is run.
- You could remove read permissions from the file with `os.chmod(file, '022')`
- Remove the file when your program closes, with `os.remove(file)`

There are ways to get around all of these defences (even deleting a file), they only make the user's task of reading the data a little harder. This is not real protection at all, and it's definitely not a good idea to rely on techniques like this to secure real data.

Comment: yes @Jamie. I do know that this is not the correct way to do it. But as I said I am running against a deadline and I made a mistake the first time around! Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'd decrypt data as needed, use it, then purge it from memory as soon as it's no longer needed without ever writing it to disk. If that design change is too much, and you're all right with just making it a bit harder for a non-technical user to access all your sensitive information, store it in memory and accept that anyone who cares enough can access it.

Failing that, some other options in order from easier to harder to access the data:

- You can hide the file, but if the user turns on show hidden files or
  uses `ls -l` they can see it.
- You can read-protect the file, but the user can change permissions on
  the file to read it.
- You can delete the file straight after using it, but the user can use data recovery tools to read the file (or just read it while the program is using it).
- You can send the file to a remote server and read it from there
  without the decrypted data ever touching the user's drive, but if
  they use a packet sniffer they can read the data.
- You can keep it solely in memory, but if the OS pages it out or the
  user inspects your program memory, they can read the data.

Comment: Sending sensitive unencrpyted data over the internet would provide much more of a security issue than just keeping the data on the user's machine! This would make the system vulnerable to the outside world, and potentially allow anyone to gain access to the data and compromise the system.

Comment: Indeed. That option only really makes sense when implementing some sort of secure API which provides the requested plaintext over HTTPS say.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more secure approach would be using memory-mapped files instead of disk files. If the size of encrypted data is not hundreds of megabytes then you could instead create the files in memory without touching the disk. Have a look at the [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) module (io.StringIO/io.BytesIO in python 3). Of course, this is not 100% safe, as there are ways to see what is stored in RAM and the data can be paged by the OS to a disk-based paging file, but it is still better 'protected' than plain text files on disk.